# Ellipses across spanning rows

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create rows where there are ellipsis from the end of the left cell to the start of the text of the right cell.  The issue is the length of the left cell varies and the length of the right cell also varies.  I've tried by aligning 2 divs and then ending the right div with overflow: ellipsis and then starting the right div with ellipsis but I don't know how to figure out how many dots should be added prior to start of the right text.

For example:

Property 1......................................Value 1

Some Property 2.................Some Value 2

Comment: Does parent element has fixed width, also could you post your html?

Comment: The parent can have a fixed width.  There is much html that works to be posted but will add a fiddle.

Comment: A not very correct but workable solution is to add a middle div with `border-bottom: 1px dotted #000000;`

Comment: Here is another example https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/540/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `flex`, `order` and a pseudo to draw the dots

```css
.ellipsis {
  display:flex;
}
.ellipsis span {
  order:2;
}
.ellipsis span:first-of-type {
  order:0;
}
.ellipsis:before {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;/* optionnal*/
  border-bottom:dotted 1px;
  flex:1;
  order:1;
  margin:0 0.2em 0.25em;/* you may tune this */
}
body {
  padding-top:50px; /* demo snippet in the way */
  }
```

```html
<p class="ellipsis"><!-- any other tag as li or div does too, CSS does the styling -->
    <span>ellipsis in</span>
    <span>between</span>
  </p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a pseudo-element and a hint of flexbox.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.list {
  display: flex;
}
.first {
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
.price {
  text-align: right;
  flex: 0 0 4em;
}
.first:after {
  content: '';
  border-bottom: dotted 1px black;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="list">
    <i class='first'>Co-Pay:</i>
    <i class="price">$150.00</i> 
  </li>
  <li class="list">
    <i class='first'>Pay:</i>
    <i class="price"> $5.00</i> 
  </li>
  <li class="list">
    <i class='first'>Co-Pay: item</i>
    <i class="price"> $15.00</i> 
  </li>
  <li class="list">
    <i class='first'>Co-Pay: great deal</i>
    <i class="price"> $1.00</i> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This answer  looks easier to grasp than http://stackoverflow.com/a/36726483/227299 since it doesn't mess with order